# What is the correct way to play the two ornaments in BWV 541?

Tags: j-s-bach, ornaments

This Prelude and Fugue for organ has two ornaments in it, and those two ornaments, in the Urtext, are the same:

In the middle of the Prelude (please excuse the score markings, and the "lighter" had to do with the organ), and at the end of the Prelude (it's not a literal "rit"):

[image]
[image]

You'll notice the ornaments in the upper right hand corners of the scanned images, which are not in [Bach's guide of ornamentation](http://practisingthepiano.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/ornaments.jpg)... has anyone a clue on how to play these or knows more about the issue?

Answer (score 1):

They look very much like the second ornament on the bottom line of the guide (idem), and I have heard them played like that. Of course, they look shorter, like a combination of that "uphook" and the mordent. With this interpretation you could also play the first one as B-A#-G#-A#, especially if your tempo is faster. I think I prefer the more finalizing effect of the longer trill, though, especially at the end of the piece.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the "Explication" as illustrating a Lego assembly kit of symbols for the start, middle, and end of ornaments. In your example the "hook" at the start means a 4-note turn, B A# G# A# in your first example, as shown in the two examples labelled "idem". This is followed by a "mordant", i.e. A# G# A#.  Dovetailing them together you get a sextuplet, B A# G# A# G# A#. Or since the note is short, you could telescope the two parts together into just four notes, B A# G# A#.

The Bach-Gesellschaft edition just has a "mordant" (see http://imslp.org/wiki/Prelude_and_Fugue_in_G_major,_BWV_541_(Bach,_Johann_Sebastian), but Baroque ornaments tend to start on the upper note unless there is a good reason no to, and it makes good musical sense here to start with B rather than play just the three notes A# G# A#.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the wavy line with a vertical line intersecting it, then it's a little complicated. It looks partly like a lower mordent but as far as I understand, in the baroque era, according to the [AB Guide to Music theory](http://shop.abrsm.org/shop/prod/Taylor-Eric-The-AB-Guide-to-Music-Theory-Part-I/598230), "Other symbols were sometimes attached to the beginning or end of a wavy line to show decorated starts or finishes to a **trill**, but *after* the baroque period these were gradually superseded by grace notes or even written out in full."
[image]

not sure if this helps though. I'm guessing you combine elements of both a lower mordent and a trill in your case, basically in a fashion similar to the second example in the image.